# LINQ "MaxOrDefault"?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I'm new to LINQ. I need to compute new_id as follows:

```
public class C_Movement
{
  public int id=-1;
  public static ObservableCollection<C_Movement> list=new ObservableCollection<C_Movement>();
  // ...
}

int new_id = (C_Movement.list.Count==0) ? 0 : C_Movement.list.Max(x => x.id)+1;
```

Is there a LINQ way to compact that expression, so that I don't have to use the `? :` structure? The problem is that, when `C_Movement.list` contains no elements, `C_Movement.list.Max(x => x.id)` returns null (and I would like it to return -1, instead).

Thank you.

Comment: How can it return null when it's returning an integer?

Comment: For future reference, the "? :" structure is actually called *the conditional operator* (in MSDN docs), but most folks call it *the ternary operator.* :)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx) method should help:

```
int new_id = C_Movement.list.Select(x => x.id).DefaultIfEmpty(-1).Max()+1;
```

Answer (score 6):

`int new_id = C_Movement.list.Max(x => (int?)x.id).GetValueOrDefault(-1) + 1;`

where `GetValueOrDefault` is a [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: It's worth noting that only Max() on collections of nullable types returns null for empty sequence while Max() in general throws exception.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
int new_id = 0;

if (C_Movement.list.Any())
    new_id = C_Movement.list.Max(x => x.id) + 1;
```

Comment: you don't need an `else` here since you've already set it to `0`

Comment: That's true, I guess I'm anal about certain things. Bad habits die hard!

Comment: The major problem with this version is that it will double enumerate the iterator. The "Any" will be the first iteration and the "Max" will be the second. This implementation should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Snowbear's answer:

```
 public static TProperty MaxOrDefault<TSource, TProperty>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                                          Func<TSource, TProperty> selector,TProperty defaultValue=default)
 {
     var items=source.Select(selector).DefaultIfEmpty(defaultValue);
     return items.Max();
 }
```

But it eludes me why 12 years later .Net does not have this.

Comment: *But it eludes me* -- Probably because then there are far more LINQ methods that also could have this addition, while it's very easy to get the desired effect by adding `DefaultIfEmpty` on either of them. Also, each new method must be documented in hundreds of languages...

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```cs
    public static class LinqExtensions
    {
        public static TValue Max<TSource, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TValue> selector, TValue defaultValueIfEmpty)
            where TValue : IComparable
        {
            if (source == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            if (selector == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selector));
            TValue sum;
            using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                    return defaultValueIfEmpty;
                sum = selector(enumerator.Current);
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    var num2 = selector(enumerator.Current);
                    if (num2.CompareTo(sum) > 0)
                        sum = num2;
                }
            }
            return sum;
        }

        public static TSource Max<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource defaultValueIfEmpty)
            where TSource : IComparable
        {
            if (source == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            TSource sum;
            using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                    return defaultValueIfEmpty;
                sum = enumerator.Current;
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    var num2 = enumerator.Current;
                    if (num2.CompareTo(sum) > 0)
                        sum = num2;
                }
            }
            return sum;
        }

    }
```

Comment: The generic type constraint `where TValue : IComparable` defeats the purpose of `defaultValueIfEmpty` because a nullable type doesn't implement `IComparable`. Besides that, (1) it's always useful when posting code exceeding a couple of lines to add some explanation, and (2) "Try this" isn't really an answer.

Comment: I meant `Nullable<T>`. My first effort trying your code failed with `int?`. About an explanation. Code itself may be easy to understand, but the process leading to that specific solution is at least as interesting.

Comment: It's the exact same Microsoft source code of Max augmented to have a default value.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs Line 1879. It uses a Comparer<TSource>.Default which implements IComparer.

Comment: That's not the same as a generic type constraint. `Comparer<int?>.Default` is an object comparing two `int?` instances. An `int?` itself is not `IComparable`, rendering your function useless for `Nullable<T>` types (and anything else that doesn't implement `IComparable`).

Comment: if the compiler does accept int? as an argument for TValue, it means it implements IComparable. If it does not, then you can not use this method. Either way, the method behave as expected.